Full Width Mega Menu not working when I add width:100%
Hi I am trying to design an Header with Mega Menu using HTML and custom CSS. I tried to set mega menu to full width by applying width:100% to it but doesn't work.
This is my HTML code
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>IT Company</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remixicon/4.2.0/remixicon.css" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/header.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="container">
        <nav class="navbar" id="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-container">
                <div class="menu-icon" id="menu-icon">
                    <button class="menu" onclick="toggleDrawer()" aria-label="Main Menu">
                        <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                            <path class="line line1"
                                d="M 20,29.000046 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,29.000046 94.498839,28.817352 94.532987,66.711331 94.543142,77.980673 90.966081,81.670246 85.259173,81.668997 79.552261,81.667751 75.000211,74.999942 75.000211,74.999942 L 25.000021,25.000058" />
                            <path class="line line2" d="M 20,50 H 80" />
                            <path class="line line3"
                                d="M 20,70.999954 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,70.999954 94.498839,71.182648 94.532987,33.288669 94.543142,22.019327 90.966081,18.329754 85.259173,18.331003 79.552261,18.332249 75.000211,25.000058 75.000211,25.000058 L 25.000021,74.999942" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="solvejet.svg" alt="IT Company Logo">
                </div>
                <div class="contact-icon">
                    <a href="#" class="contact-button">
                        <i class="ri-send-plane-fill"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a>
                    <div class="mega-menu">
                        <div class="mega-menu-content">
                            <div class="mega-menu-section">
                                <h3>Web Development</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Front-end</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Back-end</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Full-stack</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mega-menu-section">
                                <h3>Mobile Development</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">iOS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Android</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Cross-platform</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mega-menu-section">
                                <h3>Cloud Services</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">AWS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Azure</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Google Cloud</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Technology</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Hire</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Work</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="cta-button">Let's Talk</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
    <div class="drawer" id="drawer">
        <div class="drawer-content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="drawer-menu">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="drawer-menu">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="drawer-menu">Industries</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="drawer-menu">Technology</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="drawer-menu">Hire</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="drawer-menu">Work</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="/contact-us" class="drawer-cta-button">Let's Talk</a>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <script src="js/header.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

and this is my CSS
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.container {
    max-width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.navbar-container {
    padding-left: 2%;
    align-items: center;
    width: min-content;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    background: transparent;
    transition: background 0.3s ease;
    height: 80px;
}

.navbar.scrolled {
    background: rgba(255, 254, 254, 0.4);
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}

.logo img {
    height: 60px;
}

.nav-menu {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav-item {
    position: relative;
}

.nav-link {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #252B33;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.75rem 1.2rem;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 70px;
    transition: background 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
    font-size: 1.05em;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:focus {
    color: #0263E0;
}

.menu-icon {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.mega-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

}

.nav-item:hover .mega-menu {
    display: block;
    animation: cardDrop 0.5s forwards;
}

.dropdown:hover .mega-menu {
    display: block;
}

.mega-menu-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 20px;
}

.mega-menu-section {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
}

.mega-menu-section h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.mega-menu-section ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.mega-menu-section li {
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

.mega-menu-section a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cta-button {
    background: #0263E0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1.05rem 2.0rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    line-height: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    transition: background 0.3s ease;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 40px rgba(2, 99, 224, .15);
}

.cta-button:hover,
.cta-button:focus {
    background: #202c4a;
}

.drawer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 90px;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    background: rgba(255, 254, 254, 0.4);
    color: #252B33;
    z-index: 1001;
    transition: left 0.3s ease;
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}

.drawer.open {
    left: 0;
}

.drawer-content {
    padding: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 90%;
}

.drawer-content ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.contact-button {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0263E0;
}

.contact-icon {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.drawer-content li {
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.drawer-content .drawer-menu {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #252B33;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
    align-items: left;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 8px 15px;
}

.drawer-content .drawer-menu:hover,
.drawer-content .drawer-menu:focus {
    color: #ddd;
}

.drawer-cta-button {
    background: #0263E0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1.05rem 2.0rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background 0.3s ease;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: auto;
    /* Push the button to the bottom */

}

.drawer-cta-button:hover,
.drawer-cta-button:focus {
    background: #202c4a;
}


.menu {
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 6;
    transition: stroke-dasharray 600ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1),
        stroke-dashoffset 600ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.line1 {
    stroke-dasharray: 60 207;
    stroke-width: 6;
}

.line2 {
    stroke-dasharray: 60 60;
    stroke-width: 6;
}

.line3 {
    stroke-dasharray: 60 207;
    stroke-width: 6;
}

.opened .line1 {
    stroke-dasharray: 90 207;
    stroke-dashoffset: -134;
    stroke-width: 6;
}

.opened .line2 {
    stroke-dasharray: 1 60;
    stroke-dashoffset: -30;
    stroke-width: 6;
}

.opened .line3 {
    stroke-dasharray: 90 207;
    stroke-dashoffset: -134;
    stroke-width: 6;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .nav-menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu-icon {
        display: block;
    }

    .cta-button {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu {
        display: flex;
    }

    .menu-icon,
    .contact-icon {
        display: block;
    }

    .navbar-container {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    .contact-icon {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .navbar {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .nav-menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu-icon {
        display: block;
    }

    .cta-button {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu {
        display: flex;
    }

    .menu-icon,
    .contact-icon {
        display: block;
    }

    .navbar-container {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    .contact-icon {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    .mega-menu {
        left: 100%;
    }

    .mega-menu::before {
        left: 40%;
    }
    .drawer-content .drawer-menu {
        font-size: 48px;
        font-weight: 800;
    }
    .drawer-content
    {
        align-items: center;
    }
    .drawer-cta-button
    {
        width: 80%;
    }
}

@keyframes cardDrop {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

I tried to give .mega-menu width:100% but it doesn't cover full width. I tried width:1920px I still doesn't shift to full width, Is there any other way to do it?

.mega-menu does not have width:100% ... it has top: 100%; though - it's also display: none; so ... not sure how you can see it at all

I tried that, It wasn't working. top: 100% is to set Mega Menu below the menu links

but it's display: none so ... the code you added does not demonstrate the issue, because it never displays mega-menu at all

I removed display: none and added this right: 0; width: 100%; Still ain't working.

For the parent you have specified the fixed width, If you add 100% to the children element it'll take the full width of the parent element. You've to specify the width in pixels or you can simply use the width: max-content. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-content
for example:
.mega-menu {
    width: max-content;
}

Tested in chrome browser.

Although max-content might look like it works, it won't satisfy the desired behavior if the screen is larger than the content. We likely need to make sure the parent of this mega-menu element has a non-percentage width (100vw | 1000px | whatever makes sense).

yea, max-content surely helps with containing the width, but it doesn't contain the width of the full screen, But thanks for the help. :)
